# xamarin forms, autocomplete location addres

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am looking for and  Xamarin Forms Cross Platform tutorial, that will allow the user to type in an address in the textbox / Entry control, and it will auto complete.  something like google maps but without the map, and just a textbox / entry control?  Can you please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

[This package](https://github.com/ajsmithsw/PlacesSearchBar) repository and unlisted nuget package are no longer supported.

However, here are moore links that may suit your needs:

1. https://github.com/krzysztofstepnikowski/Xamarin.Forms.EntryAutoComplete
2. https://github.com/bulubuloa/SupportWidgetXF

Comment: I am new to Xamarin forms and C#.  Im coming from a .Net VB background... This looks like a great link and I thank you, but it seems like it doesn't have instructions and not familiar with how to install the package

Comment: First, what package solves your problem? You have a custom list? Or search from API, the first link suits your needs? In the link, they have all instructions on how to use it.

Comment: could you show me where are the instructions are located in each of the following links please it would help me out a lot

Comment: @RittenRA, xamarin package is install through Nuget Package.